# Swift: For Loop to iterate through enumerated array by index greater than 1

Tags: swift, for-in-loop, stride, enumerated

Is there a way to use a for-in loop through an array of strings by an index greater than 1 using .enumerated() and stride, in order to keep the index and the value?

For example, if I had the array

var testArray2: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

and I wanted to loop through by using testArray2.enumerated() and also using stride by 2 to output:

```
0, a
2, c
4, e
```

So ideally something like this; however, this code will not work:

```
for (index, str) in stride(from: 0, to: testArray2.count, by: 2){
    print("position \(index) : \(str)")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two ways to get your desired output.

1. Using only `stride`

   ```
   var testArray2: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

   for index in stride(from: 0, to: testArray2.count, by: 2) {
       print("position \(index) : \(testArray2[index])")
   }
   ```
2. Using `enumerated()` with `for in` and `where`.

   ```
   for (index,item) in testArray2.enumerated() where index % 2 == 0 {
       print("position \(index) : \(item)")
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I am just learning Swift and this is all very new syntax for me.

Comment: @Biggytiny Welcome mate :) Once you understand the syntax it is looks easy for you too.

Answer (score 3):

To iterate with a stride, you could use a `where` clause:

```
for (index, element) in testArray2.enumerated() where index % 2 == 0 {
    // do stuff
}
```

Another possible way would be to map from indices to a collection of tuples of indices and values:

```
for (index, element) in stride(from: 0, to: testArray2.count, by: 2).map({($0, testArray2[$0])}) {
    // do stuff
}
```